# System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached. (Queueable Jobs)

Tags: apex, jobs

I am chaining my Queueable jobs in an `Enterprise Org` but I am getting the following exception:

`System.AsyncException : Maximum stack depth has been reached.`

According to documentation :

> Because no limit is enforced on the depth of chained jobs, you can
> chain one job to another. You can repeat this process with each new
> child job to link it to a new child job. For Developer Edition and
> Trial organizations, the maximum stack depth for chained jobs is 5,
> which means that you can chain jobs four times and the maximum number
> of jobs in the chain is 5, including the initial parent queueable job.

My question is will an `Enterprise Org` still enforce this limit of 5 Jobs? I am a bit confused here whether the `Enterprise Org` that we spin off from `Partner Portal` are considered as Trial org or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not paying for an Enterprise Org, it is a trial. This includes orgs created in the Partner Portal, Scratch Orgs, signup pages, Trailhead Orgs, Dreamforce or other event orgs, etc. The exception to this rule are orgs that are given for free for production use, such as the Non-Profit Orgs.

If you wanted to confirm this, you can query the Organization object in the Developer Console:

```
SELECT TrialExpirationDate FROM Organization
```

If `TrialExpirationDate` is not blank, then it is a trial org.